# Shared Model between ViewPager child fragments using Dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-mvp

Hi any ideas how to implement shared `Model` or `Presenter` between `ViewPager` child fragments? Shared `ViewModel` is not an option.

Comment: `Shared ViewModel is not an option.` why not? that's the current recommendation.

Comment: Because whole project is based on MVP already

Comment: That's your own project structure's own limitation, if you dug yourself into a corner, there's nothing we can do for you. `ViewModel` isn't even a "VM" in "MVVM" anyway.

Comment: as @EpicPandaForce says SharedViewModel is the best solution, you don't have to change your structure, just create a shared view model as a class. or another way is using Event Bus maybe.

Comment: Yes, thought about these options, but still want to keep nice and consistant architecture of MVP. Thanks for advice